# How to select rows and assign them new values with SparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

In R programming language I can do following:

```r
x <- c(1, 8, 3, 5, 6)
y <- rep("Down",5)
y[x>5] <- "Up"
```

This would result in a y vector being `("Down", "Up", "Down", "Down", "Up")`

Now my x sequence is an output of the `predict` function on a linear model fit. The `predict` function in R returns a sequence while the `predict` function in Spark returns a DataFrame containing the columns of the test-dataset + the columns `label` and `prediction`.

By running

```r
y[x$prediction > .5]
```

I get the error:

```r
Error in y[x$prediction > 0.5] : invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On selecting rows:**

Your approach will not work, since `y`, as a product of Spark `predict`, is a Spark (and not R) dataframe; you should use the [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/R/filter.html) function of SparkR. Here is a reproducible example using the `iris` dataset:

```r
library(SparkR)
sparkR.version()
# "2.2.1"

df <- as.DataFrame(iris)
df
# SparkDataFrame[Sepal_Length:double, Sepal_Width:double, Petal_Length:double, Petal_Width:double, Species:string]
nrow(df)
# 150

# Let's keep only the records with Petal_Width > 0.2:
df2 <- filter(df, df$Petal_Width > 0.2)    
nrow(df2)
# 116
```

Check also the example in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/sparkr.html#selecting-rows-columns).

**On replacing row values:**

The standard practice for replacing row values in Spark dataframes is first to create a new column with the required condition, and then possibly dropping the old column; here is an example, where we replace values of `Petal_Width` greater than `0.2` with 0's in the `df` we have defined above:

```r
newDF <- withColumn(df, "new_PetalWidth", ifelse(df$Petal_Width > 0.2, 0, df$Petal_Width))
head(newDF)
# result:
  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species new_PetalWidth
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa            0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa            0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa            0.0 # <- value changed

# drop the old column:
newDF <- drop(newDF, "Petal_Width")
head(newDF)
# result:
  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Species new_PetalWidth
1          5.1         3.5          1.4  setosa            0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4  setosa            0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3  setosa            0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5  setosa            0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4  setosa            0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7  setosa            0.0
```

The method also works along different columns; here is an example of a new column taking values 0 or `Petal_Width`, depending on a condition for `Petal_Length`:

```r
newDF2 <- withColumn(df, "something_here", ifelse(df$Petal_Length > 1.4, 0, df$Petal_Width))
head(newDF2)
# result:
  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species something_here
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa            0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa            0.0
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa            0.0
```

Comment: Hello @desertnaut, thank you for your answer! But I don't want to filter the dataset, I just want to assign a specific value to those "rows" of the vector, for which the condition x$prediction > .5 will get true. Any ideas how to accomplish this? Maybe with filter-function, but only filtering is not enough